# бесконечный автоматический скроллер на js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

мне нужно сделать автоматический скролл элементов вниз.
т.е. у меня есть 4 вертикальных колонки с рандомными фотками. Мне нужно, чтоб при загрузке страницы они автоматически медленно опускались вниз, а сверху генерировались новые. При этом всё это происходит в рамках одного неподвижного элемента. Как это можно реализовать?
облазил половину интернета, не нашёл ничего по делу

Answer (score 4):

```js
let parentDiv = document.querySelector('.parent');
let childMarginBottom = 10;

function addChild(){
  let child = document.createElement('div');
  child.classList.add('child');
  child.innerText = `Дочерний элемент ${parentDiv.childElementCount}`;
  parentDiv.prepend(child);
}

while( parentDiv.scrollHeight < parentDiv.clientHeight ){
  addChild();
}

setInterval( scroll, 50 );

function scroll(){
  if( parentDiv.scrollTop <= 0 ){
    addChild();
    parentDiv.scrollTop += parentDiv.firstElementChild.offsetHeight + childMarginBottom;
  }
  
  parentDiv.scrollTop -= 1;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```